# how to write a script to automaically create a folder in /tmp in Ubuntu at startup

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, bash

I am currently having a problem in creating a folder at startup inside /tmp directory and executing a command for a server restart. What file do I have to modify in order to do this? I have heard about bash profile and some files are there to achieve this but I do not know what to do or whether changing those files suit my current need. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Ubuntu favors Upstart over rc files. Documentation for Ubuntu upstart can be found [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html). Looks like 12.04 has a file `/etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf` which looks like it has some code that execute after /tmp is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the command that creates the directory to /etc/rc.local, so it gets executed upon every reboot.

Comment: I put mkdir /tmp/mapcache
mkdir /tmp/mapcache/ms-base
chmod 777 -R /tmp/mapcache. In to the rc.local file. But still the folders not getting created.

Comment: did you add them before the exit 0?

Comment: Yes. I put them before exit 0. But nothing happens.

Comment: Try to set the execute bit on the file: 'sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local'